# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException, unable to start activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, activitynotfoundexception

I have a problem with the Manifest of my Application.
Clicking on a button on Main activity I want to start an other Activity, so I used this function:

```
public void startDatacenters() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Datacenters.class);
    activity.startActivity(intent);}
```

The package of Datacenters.class is com.eco4cloud.activities.Datacenters

So my manifest is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.eco4cloud"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.Datacenters"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.eco4cloud.activities.DATACENTERS" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Android gave me this error i don't know why :(

> 05-24 18:01:32.622: D/AndroidRuntime(15404): Shutting down VM
>   05-24 18:01:32.622: W/dalvikvm(15404): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a441f8)
>   05-24 18:01:32.632: E/AndroidRuntime(15404): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   05-24 18:01:32.632: E/AndroidRuntime(15404): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.eco4cloud/com.eco4cloud.activities.Main}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.eco4cloud/com.eco4cloud.activities.Datacenters}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
>   05-24 18:01:32.632: E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2079)
>   05-24 18:01:32.632: E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
>   05-24 18:01:32.632: E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:132)
>   05-24 18:01:32.632: E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1157)
>   05-24 18:01:32.632: E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   05-24 18:01:32.632: E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   05-24 18:01:32.632: E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
>   05-24 18:01:32.632: E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   05-24 18:01:32.632: E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   05-24 18:01:32.632: E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
>   05-24 18:01:32.632: E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
>   05-24 18:01:32.632: E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   05-24 18:01:32.632: E/AndroidRuntime(15404): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.eco4cloud/com.eco4cloud.activities.Datacenters}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
>   05-24 18:01:32.632: E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1508)
>   05-24 18:01:32.632: E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1384)
>   05-24 18:01:32.632: E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
>   05-24 18:01:32.632: E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297)
>   05-24 18:01:32.632: E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at com.eco4cloud.controllers.MainController.startDatacenters(MainController.java:46)
>   05-24 18:01:32.632: E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at com.eco4cloud.activities.Main.verifyAndSignIn(Main.java:117)
>   05-24 18:01:32.632: E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at com.eco4cloud.activities.Main.onCreate(Main.java:53)
>   05-24 18:01:32.632: E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
>   05-24 18:01:32.632: E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
>   05-24 18:01:32.632: E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>   05-24 18:01:32.632: E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    ... 11 more

Someone can help me?? 
I don't know if the problem is with the package name or others things :(

Comment: can you show us whats the package name of your main activity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do.

But a couple of suggestions to try.

```
    package="com.eco4cloud.activities" 
    // make sure package name is right.
    // probably it should be as above.
```

Mention the package name as above

Since you have explicit intent you don't require a intent-filter

```
      // use this assuming Datacenters is in package com.eco4cloud.activities
      // also assuming package="com.eco4cloud.activities"
      <activity
        android:name=".Datacenters" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
```

If package="com.eco4cloud" try the below

```
       <activity
        android:name="com.eco4cloud.activities.Datacenters" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
```

If you are starting a activity in a non-activity class

```
     public void startDatacenters() {
     Intent intent = new Intent(context, Datacenters.class);
     // assuming context is the activity content  
     context.startActivity(intent);
     //in your case you have activity.startActivity(intent)
     // not sure what activity is 
    }
```

Comment: im not able to find typo error in current AndroidManifest xml ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK <action android:name="com.eco4cloud.activities.DATACENTERS" /> its DATACENTERS while here it is Intent intent = new Intent(context, Datacenters.class);

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK any way since its explicit intents it does not matter i guess. (intent-filter).

Comment: im not sure but OP is starting Activity using class instead of Action so i thing problem is in other part.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK i am also not sure and i agree with you bcoz of this Intent intent = new Intent(context, Datacenters.class);
    activity.startActivity(intent);. No Context used to start activity. I am totally confused

Comment: if OP Activity declared as `android:name="com.eco4cloud.activities.Datacenters"` then Application work

Comment: The problem I think was the package name. Now I put com.eco4cloud.activities and ReBuild the project and all is working.... thank you for your help!

Comment: @Ferox well it was very confusing for me also. Edited many times. Glad it worked and helped you

Answer (score 0):

try providing the fully qualified name of the activity in the app manifest "com.eco4cloud.activities.Datacenters" instead of just ".activities.Datacenters"

Answer (score 0):

you can use like that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.eco4cloud"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.eco4cloud.activities.Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.eco4cloud.activities.Datacenters"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.eco4cloud.activities.DATACENTERS" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```